# "heros.solver.CountingThreadPoolExecutor - Worker thread execution failed: null Exceptions" when running nightly build soot-trunk

Tags: java, android, soot

I was converting apk file to jimple files and then converting they back to the .dex file immediately. But I cannot do the second the step successfully.

Command line used:

```
java -Xmx4g -jar soot-trunk.jar soot.Main -p cg.spark verbose:true,on-fly-cg:true -w -allow-phantom-refs -force-android-jar /home/xia/Downloads/android-platforms-master/android-17 -src-prec apk -f jimple -process-dir com.halfbrick.fruitninjafree.apk
```

In the beginning, it keeps on throwing this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing class com.google.android.gms.plus.model.moments.MomentBuffer [22,40] expecting: quoted name, identifier
at soot.JimpleClassSource.resolve(JimpleClassSource.java:61)
at soot.SootResolver.bringToHierarchy(SootResolver.java:239)
at soot.SootResolver.bringToSignatures(SootResolver.java:266)
at soot.SootResolver.bringToBodies(SootResolver.java:304)
at soot.SootResolver.processResolveWorklist(SootResolver.java:163)
at soot.SootResolver.resolveClass(SootResolver.java:131)
at soot.Scene.loadClass(Scene.java:725)
at soot.Scene.loadClassAndSupport(Scene.java:710)
at soot.Scene.loadNecessaryClasses(Scene.java:1448)
at soot.Main.run(Main.java:243)
at soot.Main.main(Main.java:147)
```

Caused by: soot.jimple.parser.parser.ParserException: [22,40] expecting: quoted name, identifier
    at soot.jimple.parser.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:1454)
    at soot.jimple.parser.JimpleAST.(JimpleAST.java:57)
    at soot.JimpleClassSource.resolve(JimpleClassSource.java:42)
    ... 10 more

I found that there are some syntax mistakes (might be) in the converted jimple file. For example, in the jimple files, there are some classes named like this:

```
         com.google.android.gms.internal.'if'
         java.lang.'annotation'.Annotation
```

Then I fixed the mistakes manually (by remove single quote and replace 'if' with other variable name like iff).

After I fixed the above mistakes, it shows another exception:

```
Warning: android.content.OperationApplicationException is a phantom class!
Warning: android.database.MatrixCursor$RowBuilder is a phantom class!
Warning: android.content.ContentProviderResult is a phantom class!
[Call Graph] For information on where the call graph may be incomplete, use the verbose option to the cg phase.
[Thread-1] ERROR heros.solver.CountingThreadPoolExecutor - Worker thread execution failed: null
[Thread-8] ERROR heros.solver.CountingThreadPoolExecutor - Worker thread execution failed: null
[Thread-7] ERROR heros.solver.CountingThreadPoolExecutor - Worker thread execution failed: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at soot.toolkits.graph.UnitGraph.(UnitGraph.java:76)
at soot.toolkits.graph.ExceptionalUnitGraph.(ExceptionalUnitGraph.java:158)
at soot.jimple.toolkits.scalar.UnreachableCodeEliminator.internalTransform(UnreachableCodeEliminator.java:79)
at soot.BodyTransformer.transform(BodyTransformer.java:51)
at soot.Transform.apply(Transform.java:105)
at soot.JimpleBodyPack.applyPhaseOptions(JimpleBodyPack.java:61)
at soot.JimpleBodyPack.internalApply(JimpleBodyPack.java:95)
at soot.Pack.apply(Pack.java:125)
at soot.jimple.JimpleMethodSource.getBody(JimpleMethodSource.java:49)
at soot.SootMethod.getBodyFromMethodSource(SootMethod.java:91)
at soot.SootMethod.retrieveActiveBody(SootMethod.java:322)
at soot.PackManager$3.run(PackManager.java:1223)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[Thread-6] ERROR heros.solver.CountingThreadPoolExecutor - Worker thread execution failed: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at soot.toolkits.graph.UnitGraph.(UnitGraph.java:76)
at soot.toolkits.graph.ExceptionalUnitGraph.(ExceptionalUnitGraph.java:158)
at soot.jimple.toolkits.scalar.UnreachableCodeEliminator.internalTransform(UnreachableCodeEliminator.java:79)
at soot.BodyTransformer.transform(BodyTransformer.java:51)
at soot.Transform.apply(Transform.java:105)
at soot.JimpleBodyPack.applyPhaseOptions(JimpleBodyPack.java:61)
...
```

At first I think it's the bug of the tool, but the answer of other question says that the bug has been fixed. But I still get this problem. Does any one know where the problem is? Thank you very much.